# terminate called without an active exception (Multithreaded merge sort)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mergesort

Hey I am new to c++ and I'm trying to create a multi threaded merge sort however i keep on getting this error.
*When the array is 1000 integers the threaded merge sort seems to work however when I initialize the array to a larger number such as 10000 integers, it gives me such exception: "terminate called without an active exception"
Your help will be much appreciated!
Down below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctime>// include this header 

using namespace std;


void shuffle(int *arr, size_t n)
{
    if (n > 1) 
    {
        size_t i;
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
          size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
          int t = arr[j];
          arr[j] = arr[i];
          arr[i] = t;
        }
    }
}


// A function to merge the two half into a sorted data.
void merge(int *a, int low, int high, int mid)
{
    // We have low to mid and mid+1 to high already sorted.
    int i, j, k, temp[high-low+1];
    i = low;
    k = 0;
    j = mid + 1;

    // Merge the two parts into temp[].
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
        {
            temp[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[k] = a[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    // Insert all the remaining values from i to mid into temp[].
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        temp[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

    // Insert all the remaining values from j to high into temp[].
    while (j <= high)
    {
        temp[k] = a[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }


    // Assign sorted data stored in temp[] to a[].
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        a[i] = temp[i-low];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int A[], int low, int high){

        if (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        thread sort_thread1(mergeSort,std::ref(A),low,mid);
        thread sort_thread2(mergeSort,std::ref (A), mid + 1, high);
        sort_thread1.join();
        sort_thread2.join();
        merge(A, low, high, mid);
    }
    return;
}
int main(){

    int size =10000;
    int A[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        A[i] = i;
    }
    shuffle(A, size);
    //for (int i=0; i<size; i++){//
      //  printf("%d ", A[i]);
    //}//
    int low = 0;
    int high = size-1;
    int start_s=clock();
    // the code you wish to time goes here
    mergeSort(A,low,high);

    int stop_s=clock();
    cout << "time: " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;

    //for(int i = 0; i<size;i++){
        //cout << A[i] << endl;`
    //}
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: `std::ref(A)` doesn't look correct.  You're nut using references so you shouldn't need it.

Comment: @user0042 I'm using geany on windows and I don't think Geany allow debugging mode.

Comment: @NathanOliver I removed the std::ref(A) but I'm still getting the error

Comment: @Moi You can always use a debugger from the command line if the IDE doesn't support it. Also not there's already an implementation for `std::shuffle()` you don't need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

This code creates too many threads.

When it cannot create more threads `std::thread` constructor throws an exception. The exception starts unwinding the stack calling destructors of existing `std::thread` objects. [`std::thread::~thread` destructor is problematic because it calls `std::terminate` if the thread is joinable but has not been joined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

See [Discussion about std::thread and RAII](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0206r0.html) for more details.

A fix for this code would be to:

- Keep the current thread busy sorting, instead of waiting on the other 2 threads, hence halving the thread count.
- Sort small arrays without creating new threads.

Example:

```
void mergeSort(int A[], int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if(high - mid > 500) {
            thread sort_thread1(mergeSort,std::ref(A), low, mid);
            mergeSort(A, mid + 1, high); // Keep this thread busy.
            sort_thread1.join();
        }
        else { // Sort small arrays using 1 thread only.
            mergeSort(A, low, mid);
            mergeSort(A, mid + 1, high);
        }
        merge(A, low, high, mid);
    }
}
```